# Is it possible to synchronize the ldap data in gluu with an rdbms?

Tags: gluu

I've been reading a bit about gluu. It uses an ldap or a couchbase backend. I need some of the user data (at least the immutable user identifier) to be replicated to an RDBMS (let's say postgresql).

Is it possible? Also, am I out to lunch trying to achieve this? [Cas](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.1.x/) and [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_database) offer the option to hook the product to an rdbms, so I would say no - but it might be an anti-pattern.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to sync LDAP and SQL/others using [LSC](https://github.com/lsc-project/lsc)

You can also post your question in https://support.gluu.org to talk directly to the team for further details.